# ploneformgen confirm data before submit

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I am creating a multi-stage form with ploneformgen. I would like to add a confirmation page showing all the data that has been entered, before the form is finally submitted. Something similar to a thank-you page, but with a submit button.

/Iz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.pfgpreview

Comment: Oh, hey, that's a much better answer than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but I think you can probably adapt the "hidden field" technique at http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen/documentation/how-to/create-a-multi-page-form to accomplish this.  Combine with how the "thank-you" template displays the submitted fields.